# Unable to edit any product once saved in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I have magento v1.9.0.1 installed on my website www.shopeling.com. I am facing an error that once I saved a product then I am not able to edit it in the future because the button "Save" and "Save & Continue" doesn't work at all.

Please help me regarding this...

Thanks

Comment: In addition to above: once i click thede two button nothing happen(not even showing loading).

Comment: Right click->Inspect Element->Console (see if there are JS error related  to this).

Comment: @Hatef Hi thanks for your reply...I am getting this error in console "TypeError: Object is not a function (near '...}...')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint to the answer is given by @hatef Right click->Inspect Element->Console (see if there are JS error related to this).

Just disable "Merge JavaScript Files" in Developer setting and clear your cache Thats all !!